# Topic Modelling

Tags: nlp, topic-modeling, topicmodels

I have an excel sheet with 6000 records each representing a message which I want to give it a topic for example is it related to sports or news and so on and I want to figure it out from the words inside the sentence.I want an easy program with a result without coding just give it the excel sheet get the categories as it is a small part in my Masters Thesis task

Answer (score 0):

The [Stanford Topic Modeling Toolbox](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/) may be just what you are looking for. It includes "Import and manipulate text from cells in Excel and other spreadsheets."